# Sending asp.net page content to Microsoft Word using contenttype

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, content-type

I have an Asp.net page, and I'd like to send it's content (ie. the rendered page) to open in Microsoft Word. I have the below code in my Page_Load event.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Output.doc");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();            
    }
```

I know I can user Response.Write to get information into the Word doc, but how do I get the rendered page content into it?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply remove the Response.Flush() and Response.End() lines and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your code in Pageload event of page.

Comment: I should have said, that code is in my Page_Load - I've edited the question.